# How to create a SSL SOAP Client in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-services, ssl, soap, node-soap

*First of all, I'd like to make it clear this is my very first time dealing with certificates/keys/pfx/etc.. so please correct me if I'm wrong :)*

I'm using [`node-soap`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) to create a client to a web-server and consume its' WSDL. Doing so only on `HTTP` protocol and not `HTTPS` i had success and everything worked just fine, but now with the `pfx` I get the `mac verify failure` error.

the relevant code:

```
import * as soap from 'soap';
import * as fs from 'fs';

let client_options: {
    forceSoap12Headers: true,
    wsdl_options:{
      pfx: fs.readFileSync('PATH\TO\MY\PFX')
    }
};

soap.createClient('HTTPS\WEB-SERVER\URL?wsdl', client_options, (error, client)=>{
    console.log(error.message) // <-- mac verify failure
    console.log(client) // <-- undefined
});
```

***Worth noting:***

- I could not find any documentation of the `node-soap` library for the -- `wsdl_options` property, the `pfx` one i accidently found while googling so i dont know any other options available.
- Trying to deal with this error, i found that an option of `passphrase: 'password'` should be added to options BUT for options of `createServer` with the `https` library, not for creating a client with `node-soap`..  relevant links: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859121/mac-verify-failure-using-node-with-ssl-certificate) , [git issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7407)

I've been dealing with this for the past 3 days, got to debugging all `node-soap`, `https`, and `request` libraries.. got lost in there.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

did you see this link in github? https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7407 it also says set `passphrase: 'password'` in this case

Comment: I had a issue with node-soap that its never be setteled finaly I was forced to use XMLHttpRequest package of nodejs and set my sop client manualy with xml code then the problem resolved I refer you to use this package if your problem does not resolve

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the linked issue already exists in my question as -git issue- and it does not refer to dealing with the error in `node-soap`. Maybe you could extend your answer to provide the use of XMLHttpRequets to create a custom client with the pfx, would be much appreciated